# Wikipedia API - Get random page with links

Tags: jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I know there is this code, `generator=random`, to get a random page but it doesn't work with my code below :

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=Little_Richard&callback=?
```

This URL comes from [this great article](http://www.9bitstudios.com/public/web/demos/blog/wikipedia-blurb/).

I have used `action=parse`, `prop=text` and `page=Page_Name` because it's the only way (that I found) to get the links with the text.

You can see this the result of my whole code [here](http://julesvaulont.com/wiki2/) (this code doesn't work on JSFiddle or CodePen).

Anybody know if there is a way to get a random page with this method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please try and re-format your question, add code in your question and avoid external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generators are a feature of `action=query`. For any other action you will need to do two separate requests.

Or you can just fetch `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random?action=render` and follow the redirect.